# Set size of button drawable in XML to image size

Tags: android, button, size, drawable

I am attempting to create buttons with text and a drawableTop. I want the drawableTop to be the regular size of the stored image since I have different sizes for different screen sizes. Setting height and width to match_parent seems to be based on the text, and setting them to dip values changes the size of the button, but not the image. I tried scaleX and scaleY, but that changes the size of the text as well, which I don't want.

I am using the following, but the image appears much smaller than what it is saved as

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/label"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_image" />
```

Is there anyway of creating a button with an image that automatically sets to it's full size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a normal ImageView and set an onClickListener or XML onClick property for it.

If you want different states (e.g. pressed and unpressed) for it you can use a drawable defined in xml to set those.

Answer (score 1):

In doc [TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), it says:

```
The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.
```

But, the reason the button isn't set the drawable to it's full size, is that we put the image to wrong res/drawable folder in app project.
You may try to put the image to other drawable folder, such as drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc. The image will show in different size. Please check out this doc [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).